# How to I send an email via apps script, mark a particular row as sent, but knowing the row data is variable and will update

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm a newbie to apps script, so please forgive my cobbled together approach here.

My data originates form a BigQuery connection, so the data could change as often as hourly.

I've have the email working under the conditions I want and my daily trigger set up to run the function.  I have conditions under which an email would send.  1. When the FSI status = 'Confirmed' and 2. When the FSI status = 'Alert'.  The second condition in the code for mailsent was my preparation for when I had a something indication an email was already sent.

However, my next step is to indicate the rows where an email has been sent, and be able to have that indication be dynamic with the row data if it were to update based on the BigQuery connection refreshing.

So here's an example of the data (again, this is a BigQuery connection extract that will change):

| Order_Status | PO | PO_REV | Vendor | Order_Date | FSI_Date | FSI_Status | Cargo*_*Ready Date | Expected_Receipt Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ready | 001 |  | Vendor1 | 5/25/2023 | 8/2/2023 | Confirm | 8/14/2023 | 9/19/2023 |
| ready | 002 | A | Vendor1 | 5/25/2023 | 8/7/2023 | Confirm | 8/14/2023 | 10/3/2023 |
| production | 003 |  | Vendor1 | 6/26/2023 | 8/10/2023 | Confirm | 8/17/2023 | 9/22/2023 |
| new | 004 |  | Vendor2 | 6/26/2023 | 8/15/2023 | pending | 8/22/2023 | 10/10/2023 |

Here's my current code:

```
function main() {
 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("FSI PO Summary");
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, numRows - 1, 10).getValues();

  for(var index in range) {

    
    var row = range[index];
    var vendor = row[3];
    var status = row[6];
    var po = row[1];
    var fsi = row[5];
    var mailsent = row[9];


if(fsistatuscheckapp(status, mailsent)) {
//If yes, send an email reminder
emailReminder(po);
}



if(fsistatuscheckalert(status, mailsent)) {
//If yes, send an email reminder
emailAlert(po);
}

}
}


var url = "https://url.com";
var tem = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Email Template");
tem.url = url;




function fsistatuscheckapp(status, mailsent) {

  if(status === 'Confirm' && mailsent === '') {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}


function fsistatuscheckalert(status, mailsent) {

  if(status === 'Alert' && mailsent === '') {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}


function emailReminder(po) {
    var email_body = tem.evaluate().getContent(); 

  MailApp.sendEmail( 
    {to: "email@email.com",
      subject: "FSI Approval Needed:" + po,
      htmlBody: email_body,
    });
  
  }


function emailAlert(po) {
    var email_body = tem.evaluate().getContent(); 

  MailApp.sendEmail( 
    {to: "email@email.com",
      subject: "FSI Schedule Date Needed:" + po,
      htmlBody: email_body,
    });
    
  }
```

Comment: Perhaps you could consider adding a send date column.  If the send date is in the past then don't send it.  When you update the contents of a row update the send date as well.  You may also want a sent column so that on the given send date you will know whether or not the email has been sent.  It kind of depends upon how you intend to execute the function

Comment: I'll have to think on this idea and see what I can get to work.  Thanks for the feedback!